# Unity sound not playing

Tags: audio, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to play a sound, but it's not playing

Here's my code:

```
public void Replay()
{
  playAudio ();
  Application.LoadLevel (Application.loadedLevel);
}

void playAudio()
{
    AudioSource audio = GetComponent<AudioSource> ();

    audio.Play();
}
```

When a button clicked, I'm calling `Replay()`. But, the sound is not played.

If I remarked`Application.LoadLevel (Application.loadedLevel);`, the sound plays normally.

What should I do to make the sound play with `Application.LoadLevel()`?

Comment: Are you certain that you have your `AudioListener`s in place when you played the sound file? Is your `AudioClip` a 2D or 3D sound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AudioSource playing the sound will get removed before it has time to finish.

Here is an alternative solution using yield to wait for the sound to finish.

```
public void Replay()
{
    StartCoroutine("ReplayRoutine");
}

IEnumerator ReplayRoutine()
{
    AudioSource audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();

    audio.Play();
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(audio.clip.length);

    Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You call play method and you load the scene after it. Try to call `playAudio()` before loading level.

```
public void Replay() {
    Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
    playAudio();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't give the chance to the audio source to play the sound, because after executing play, you immediately re-loaded the scene, so the same instance of audio source does not exist anymore, a new instance is created which has not yet received the play command. You can use some small delay using co-routine or other ways to give the needed time to the audio source. ( If you want to play the sound before loading level, otherwise just play the sound in a Start() callback)